# Can I copy and paste from one .gitignore to second .gitignore file?

Tags: git, gitignore

The issue is, I've read some documentaries but couldn't understand how to use gitignore correctly, hence I found a `.gitignore` file from another project and I want to ask, will it work if I just copy and paste one to another?

Talking about this example

```
################################################################################
# This .gitignore file was automatically created by Microsoft(R) Visual Studio.
################################################################################

/.vs
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep, `.gitignrore` is a text file.

- You can use this site to generate it for you https://gitignore.io.
- Each line in a `.gitignore` file specifies a pattern.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely try this.

Comment: My goal is to avoid from this kind of folders " /.vs
/WebMarket.WebSite/obj/Debug
    /WebMarket.WebSite/bin   " Sorry but I couldn't figer how gitignore.io will help in this case :/

Answer (score 0):

It will worked. So just trie it. You can‘t loss anything. If you have pattern like `/.vs` in your `.gitignore`, and no file will match to this pattern, nothing will happens.

A nice `.gitignore` documentation you can find here: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

I hope I could help you

Comment: Thanks I will Try :)